# How to get ride of empty squares in wx.dataview.TreeListCtrl

Tags: python, python-3.6, wxpython

I am using the following code to create a TreeList:

```
tree = wx.dataview.TreeListCtrl(self, -1, style=wx.TR_DEFAULT_STYLE | \
                                        wx.TR_FULL_ROW_HIGHLIGHT | \
                                        wx.TR_EDIT_LABELS
tree.AppendColumn("Item Name")
node = tree.AppendItem(parent_node, text)
```

And for some reason there's an empty square (see image bellow)

[image]

I even tried to add item as this:

```
node = tree.AppendItem(parent_node, text, wx.NO_IMAGE, wx.NO_IMAGE)
```

or

```
node = tree.AppendItem(parent_node, text)
tree.SetItemImage(node, wx.NO_IMAGE, wx.NO_IMAGE)
```

But none worked... any hint?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the wx.TR_DEFAULT_STYLE setting, this enables rendering check-boxes in each row.